# trying to center img in col (Bootstrap 3.3.7)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, col

I've been trying to center an image in a col with bootstrap but couldn't figure out how to do it
i would appreciate help

(https://gyazo.com/156b8d341d0bcc7777527fdf0139b3be)

The row above the blue line is what i want, but under the blue line is what i have with this code (The square in the "col" is the image)

jsfiddle.net/1cjbfs29/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
#Dennis, #Thomas {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Addition after seeing the last js fiddle with the real, complete code:

Also, remove the `float: left` from both images and change the class of the two DIV containers to `col-sm-6` only (There is no reason for that `col-sm-5`, in which the images are centered)

Comment: Then you have to post more Code, HTML and CSS. With the code you posted alone, this would work.

Comment: But it works in there as I wrote it - see updated Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/dncbmxns/1/

Comment: Look at my third version with more css at the bottom of the bootstrap css jsfiddle.net/1cjbfs29/3/

Comment: Ah  - that's a lot more relevant code than you had posted! Well, remove the `float: left` from both images and change the class of the two DIV containers to `col-sm-6 ` only (There is no reason for that `col-sm-5`, in which the images are centered)

Comment: Yup it worked i am kinda stupid for forgetting that i had float lefts in there thats why it wouldn't work